# Install apk with obb using ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to install apk file with obb data to my Android phone using ADB command prompt. I know the way to install apk directly is through `adb install App.apk` but how do I add obb files along with this?

Comment: you need to manually put `obb` file to appropriate directory. ADB should be still able to do that

Answer (score 1):

On my Android-based OUYA console, the obb files are stored in `/sdcard/Android/obb/` directory.

Each game has a subdirectory with its package name, e.g. `com.square_enix.android_googleplay.FFIII_GP`. Inside that directory are the actual `.obb` files for the game.

I needed to be root to write into that directory.

`pm list packages` on `adb shell` shows you the package names of all installed apps.